# How to edit data into database using ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been looking at examples to edit data into the database, and i keep finding this code:

```
var std = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I was wondering, how do I use this code into MY website, because I used a different method.
The main part of this question is the **EDIT** part, i don't know to to transform the above example into my edit. I can't really understand what is the "studentList" in my code.

Also, this is the link i'm following:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc

```
 namespace hdsportal.Pages

{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        List<GestaoAlertas> addresses = new List<GestaoAlertas>();
        List<GestaoUtilizadores> addresses2 = new List<GestaoUtilizadores>();

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            con.ConnectionString = "secret";
        }

        public IActionResult Gestao_Alertas()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }

        public IActionResult Gestao_Utilizadores()
        {
            FetchData2();
            return View(addresses2);
        }
      

        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int ID = 0)
        {
            GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
            return View(_teste);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacidade()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contatos()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult QuemSomos()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private void FetchData()
        {
                if (addresses.Count > 0)
                {

                    addresses.Clear();
                }
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.Connection = con;
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [SYSTEM_NAME], [SYSTEM_STATUS], [SYSTEM_SHORTMSG] FROM [CORE_SYS_STATUS]";
                    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        addresses.Add(new GestaoAlertas()
                        {
                            ID = (int)dr["ID"]
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_NAME = dr["SYSTEM_NAME"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_STATUS = dr["SYSTEM_STATUS"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_SHORTMSG = dr["SYSTEM_SHORTMSG"].ToString()

                        });
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    }
              //Mostra o erro se houver um
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   throw ex;
                }
        }

        private void FetchData2()
        {
            //Reinicia a varíavel addresses se já conter algo
            if (addresses2.Count > 0)
            {

                addresses2.Clear();
            }
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "SELECT [NumMec], [NomeCompleto], [Activo] FROM [CORE_USERS] WHERE [Activo] = 1 ";
                dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())           
                {
                    //Lê os dados da base de dados 
                    addresses2.Add(new GestaoUtilizadores()
                    {
                        NumMec = dr["NumMec"].ToString()
                    ,
                        NomeCompleto = dr["NomeCompleto"].ToString()
                    ,
                        Activo = dr["Activo"].ToString()

                    });
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: In that comment, `studentList` is probably an Entitiy Framework object representing a database table. So basically in that line would be identifying the exact record in the table which needs to updating. Assuming you're in the process of submitting the data, then you'd set the properties of the object according to the data submitted in the form, and save the changes. This is the EF equivalent of running an UPDATE query in SQL. But you seem to be using ADO.NET rather than EF so it's perhaps not relevant to you.

Comment: You should probably research various approaches, then pick the one that you like best and follow some tutorials for that approach. If you want to do [raw ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-and-modifying-data) like you're doing, that's fine. You might also look into micro-ORMs such as [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/), or a full fledged ORM such as Entity Framework, [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), or NHibernate. When following tutorials, make sure they're for your chosen library.

Comment: A side note, you have `throw ex;` in your code where `ex` is an exception you caught. This causes you to lose your stack trace, and makes debugging much more painful. To preserve the stack trace, you can just `throw;`. However, since you're not doing anything meaningful in your catch block, you might as well remove that whole try/catch. It's just adding visual clutter to your code.